# How to lazy load a uibinded GWT Editor

Tags: java, gwt, editor, lazy-loading

I guess it is too long (and perhaps inaccurate to attempt) to explain GWT Editors. Also, because I consider myself as having rudimentary understanding of mechanisms of Editors. So please don't fault me for brevity.

Here is my code tying the editor var to the uibinder template,

```
@Path("canon.doer") 
@UiField ShenandoerEditor shanonEditor;
```

Due to the @path specification, it seems impossible to lazy-load the editor.

To demonstrate the issue, even without lazy-loading, but decoupling the construction like this,

```
@UiFactory ShenandoerEditor mkShanonEditor{
    return new ShenandoerEditor();
}
```

results in error during GWT.create

> "could not find getter path ...

Are there any stragedies I could take to allow lazy loading of GWT Editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the Editor generator looks at any method that returns an editor, so it'll treat your `mkShanonEditor` method as a getter for a subeditor. Because it has no `@Path`, it thus uses the method name to infer the *path* within the edited object, trying out `mkShanonEditor` and `mkShanon`, and it doesn't find such getters in your edited object.

You only need to annotate `mkShanonEditor` with `@Editor.Ignore`.

Now, for the lazy-loading part, you'd have to create the `ShenandoerEditor` no later than `ValueAwareEditor#setValue`, or the editor won't populate it.

Comment: Thku4ur wise words of wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

The Editor need to have a reference to the widget in order to actually use it - to push in values before you show the form later. What you are asking for is for the editor to be able to notice `shanonEditor` is null, and somehow know to check back later (when? when you assign it? when the form is made visible?) to try passing in sub-values again. This doesn't make sense, and isn't how editors are meant to work.

Instead, consider pre-populating this field - i.e. don't make it lazy. How much are you presently gaining by making it lazy - are you making this lazy to put off building all of these until `createAndBind`? Can you allow just the editors to be created aggressively, and leave the panels, etc off until asWidget/createAndBind?

Assuming so, assuming you are either implementing `IsWidget` directly or extending `LazyPanel`, and that you will almost certainly want those sub-editors to be drawn (just not *yet*, i.e. wait a moment or two, as opposed to never wanting them), go ahead and aggressively create the leaf value editors (fields, etc), and the sub-editors (sub-panels), but in each step down, put off actually assembling those constituent parts into a panel until actually needed. This probably involves `@UiField(provided=true)` to indicate that these fields are populated before `createAndBind` needs to be called:

```
public class CompanyEditor implements Editor<Company>, IsWidget {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, CompanyEditor> {}
    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField(provided = true)
    TextBox name = new TextBox();

    @UiField(provided = true)
    PersonEditor owner = new PersonEditor();

    private Widget root;

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        if (root == null) {
            root = binder.createAndBind(this);
        }
        return root;
    }
}

public class PersonEditor implements Editor<Person>, IsWidget {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, CompanyEditor> {}
    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField(provided = true)
    TextBox firstName = new TextBox();

    @UiField(provided = true)
    TextBox lastName = new TextBox();

    @UiField(provided = true)
    @Path("address.city")
    TextBox city = new TextBox();

    private Widget root;
    @Override 
    public Widget asWidget() {
        if (root == null) {
            root = binder.createAndBind(this);
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```